# How can I avoid having to check undefined context values in my children when using React Context?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following:

```
type ExploreState = {
  loading: boolean;
  posts?: Post[] // array of objects, has id and some other attrs
}

const ExploreStateContext = React.createContext<ExploreState>({
  loading: true
});

const ExploreStateProvider: React.FunctionComponent = (props) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [posts, setPosts] = React.useState<Post[]>();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    // fetch posts
    setPosts(posts);
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);

  if (loading) { return <div>Loading</div> }

  return (
    <ExploreStateContext.Provider value={{ loading, posts}}>
      {props.children} 
    </ExploreStateContext.Provider>
}
```

Now, if I use this context in some child component, I run into an issue where I have to check if `posts` is `undefined` which is really annoying.

```
const { posts } = React.useContext(ExploreStateContext)

posts.map(doSomething) // posts is possibly undefined!!!
```

Is there a good way to avoid this undefined checking?

Comment: So, is this a case where posts will never be undefined?

Comment: @RohanAgarwal Yes that is correct.  I will handle the other cases, but I want posts to never be undefined to the children.

Comment: By looking into `ExploreStateProvider` it's a bit strange that posts could be `undefined`. It's clear that you have initial state for posts as empty array. Try removing initial state from `ExploreStateContext` or add `posts: []` to it as well. For typescript I would remove `?` - optional for posts.

Comment: I'm fetching posts via API, which is why it is undefined initially because I'm throwing up a loading state while I get the posts.

Comment: @a person then you might give my answer below a try.

Answer (score 1):

May be you are looking for the [optional chaining operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining)

You use like this `posts?.map(post => ...)`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid undefined checking, append `!` at the end of the variable from which the check needs to be removed.

Eg. `posts!.map(doSomething)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid checking, empty array as initial value for post might work for you. In other words don't let posts to ever be `undefined`.